# Combine Table Records per Day to Create 'Last Week' page

Tags: mysql, date, count

I apologize if this has been asked before.. I'm very new to developing and although I've tried searching a lot, I'm not really sure what to look for.

Anyway so I have a table which counts records being entered per day. It looks something like this (each record is represented by a letter) (assume today's date is 27/01/2013):

```
RECORD | COUNT | DATE 
------A-----|-----4-----|27/01/2013  
------B-----|-----7-----|27/01/2013
------B-----|-----3-----|24/01/2013
------C-----|-----8-----|22/01/2013 
------A-----|-----2-----|19/01/2013
```

Each new post is checked in the table and it updates the count if the record already exists on the current day, otherwise a new record is created.

For the page which prints the records which have been added 'TODAY', I have the MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC, `count` DESC LIMIT 1000
```

and use a php 'if' statement to only print the records where the date('Y-m-d') = `date` in the table. So only the records and the corresponding count which has been entered that day are printed.
- the table above would produce the result:

```
1. B 7 
2. A 4
```

What I would like is a page which prints the records which have been entered in the last week. I know I can use `DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()`, to print the records from last week but I need to duplicate records to be combined and the counts added together.. so the result for this table would look like this:

```
1. B 10
2. C 8 
3. A 4
```

How would I go about combining those duplicate records and have a list of records ordered by count? Is this the best method to get a 'last week' record count, or is there another table structure which would be better?

Again I'm sorry if this a silly question or if my explanation was long-winded, but just some simple pointers will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT `record`, SUM(`count`) AS `count` 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
 GROUP BY `record`
 ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

And you can `LIMIT 1000` grouped resultset if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Using [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) will allow you group related records together

```
SELECT `record`
     , SUM(`count`) AS `count`
FROM `table` 
WHERE `date` > `date` - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
GROUP BY `record`
ORDER BY `count` DESC 
LIMIT 1000
```